# GeekQuiz requires SQL Server 2012 Express, I have SQL Server 2014 - how to upgrade?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I've been playing around with the [Microsoft GeekQuiz sample](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) but recently updated Visual Studio/SQL Server to newer versions.

When loading it I got the following:

[image]

There is no database file in my solution explorer, and as far as I know the GeekQuiz sample creates the database in the `TriviaContext` so there wouldn't be one anyway unless I'm mistaken about how this all works?

Comment: @marc_s could you post that as an answer so I can mark it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the **connection string** in the `GeekQuiz` solution to point to your already installed SQL Server 2014 instance.

No need to "upgrade" (or downgrade) your SQL Server - SQL Server 2012 Express and SQL Server 2014 are sufficiently similar that (almost) anything that runs on SQL Server 2012 Express will also happily run on an already installed SQL Server 2014 "full" installation.